# Is there any other inner product on $C[0,1]$ other than integral of product over [0,1]?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

Is there any other inner product on $C[0,1]$ other than integral of product over [0,1]?

Till now I just come across only one inner product on that space. I am interested in knowing other

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks a lot

Comment: If $q_n$ is an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$, then $$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_n 2^{-n}f(q_n)\cdot\overline{g(q_n)}$$ is an inner product.

Comment: You should specify what properties do you want your inner product to satisfy (do you want it to be faithful, so that $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$ iff $f = 0$.  I think the integral of $f\cdot g$ with respect to any probability measure whose support is dense in $[0,1]$ satisfies that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first idea would be to have a weighted integral:
$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)w(x)dx,
$$
where $w$ is a strictly positive function in $[0,1]$.

Another idea would be to have a countable dense set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ in $[0,1]$, and then define, for example
$$
\langle f,g\rangle= \sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}f(x_k)g(x_k).
$$

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about space over $\Bbb R$.

Note that for any (measurable) function $k:[0,1]\to (0,1]$, the function
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_k = \int_0^1 k(x)f(x)g(x)\,dx
$$
defines an inner product.  There are inner products that don't fall into this category, such as those of the form
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_{k,w} = \int_0^1 k(x)f(x)g(x)\,dx + \sum_{k} w_k f(w_k)g(w_k).
$$
That being said, even these can be written in the form of $\langle f,g \rangle _k$ if we use a suitable [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) $k$.